# Probability of victory for player in static two-player game

Tags: probability, game-theory

This is probably a simple one, but I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the probability of **victory for player 1** in a static two-player game, where the history of games between the two is (player 1: 6 victories, player 2: 4 victories).

I'm not much good at Maths, so my initial efforts have just been to divide the number of games won by the total number of games played. So, 6/10 = 60%.

What I'd like to avoid is the situation where, after game 1, there is a probability distribution of 100 : 0.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, show us your effort.

Comment: I've updated the question with my effort, Jaroslaw.

Comment: The simplest thing to do is what you did.  There are some problems if, say, you stopped after the first game.  If player 1 won the first game then after that you would have said that player 1 had a probability of 100% of winning, which is clearly wrong (since B went on to win). There are ways around this sort of problem.  Which way is best probably depends on why you're asking this question.

Comment: @michaellugo I was trying to avoid the 100% after 1 game problem, yes. Ideally, the 50% for player 1 / 50% for player 2 would become something more like 52% for player 1 / 48% for player 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability of World Series - Using Pascal and Fermat "Problem of Points"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604369/probability-of-world-series-using-pascal-and-fermat-problem-of-points)

Comment: This is a variation on the Problem of Points; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_points